# How should I use JSONFindAndModifyCommand?

Tags: scala, playframework, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I have no idea how I should use play-reactivemongo's `JSONFindAndModifyCommand`.

I need to make an upsert query by some field. So I can first remove any existing entry and then insert. But Google says that FindAndModify command has `upsert: Boolean` option to achieve the same result.

Suppose I have two `play.api.libs.json.JsObject`s: query and object.

```
val q = (k: String) => Json.obj("sha256" -> k)

val obj = (k: String, v: String) => Json.obj(
    "sha256" -> k,
    "value" -> v
)
```

Then I do:

```
db.collection.findAndModify(
    q(someSha256),
    what?!,
    ...
)
```

I use play2-reactivemongo 0.11.9

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [this example](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/blob/0.11.x/driver/samples/SimpleUseCasesSample.scala#L186)?

Answer (score 0):

The simpler is to use the collection operations [`findAndUpdate`](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/api/index.html#reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericCollection@findAndUpdate[Q,U](selector:Q,update:U,fetchNewObject:Boolean,upsert:Boolean,sort:Option[GenericCollection.this.pack.Document],fields:Option[GenericCollection.this.pack.Document])(implicitselectorWriter:GenericCollection.this.pack.Writer[Q],implicitupdateWriter:GenericCollection.this.pack.Writer[U],implicitec:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[GenericCollection.this.BatchCommands.FindAndModifyCommand.FindAndModifyResult]) or `findAndRemove`, e.g.

```
val person: Future[BSONDocument] = collection.findAndUpdate( BSONDocument("name" -> "James"), BSONDocument("$set" -> BSONDocument("age" -> 17)), fetchNewObject = true) // on success, return the update document: // { "age": 17 }
```